# Display subcategories of a specifc category in side bar

Tags: php, magento, navigation, categories, sidebar

I'm using Hellowired theme, top navigation links are displayed in side bar. Instead I want subcategories of a specific category(ID 3) to be displayed in sidebar. Please keep in mind active inactive status should work when user navigates through links.

Here is the code in leftnav.phtml :

```
 <div class="block block-leftnav">
 <div class="block-title"><strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop Categories') ?></span></strong></div>
 <div class="block-content">
 <ul id="leftnav">
 <!-- HOME BUTTON HACK -->

 <?php $_anyActive = false; foreach ($this->getStoreCategories(3) as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); } ?>
 <li class="home <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
 <!-- HOME BUTTON HACK -->
 <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories(3) as $_category): ?>
 <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 </ul>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

Help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Vickey: This question is for Magento, not wordpress

Comment: sorry i forget to check its for  wordpress  function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '3' in load(3) is the category ID.

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();

    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
    {
      $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
      if($_category->getIsActive()) {
        $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
        foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
        {
              $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
              if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                  echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View products for "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
              }
         }
      }
    }
```